# 1 form 2 tables - MS ACCESS

Tags: forms, ms-access

Is there a way to set up 1 form to populate 2 tables? But I would like any subsequent changes to the second table to be completed via another form.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the tables are related to each other, set up a Relationship between the two (click on Tools, and then Relationships in A2003) and set the relationship to Enforce Referrential Integrity.

If the tables are unrelated, then you will have to use a query or write some VBA code to populate both tables, and run them through a form-related event (OnClick for a button, or OnLostFocus if you want the query/VBA to run automatically when the user moves off a specific textbox).

Comment: What would the update statement look like if i wanted to update all of Table A to Table B?

Comment: Are you appending it, or updating it?  I'm not sure how they're related or what fields are in them, so I can't really give you a clear answer on that.

Comment: I'm looking to append records from `Table A` to `Table B`, if a record from `Table A` does not exist in `Table B`. Lets say `Table A` had fields `ID_NUMBER`, `DTL_1`, `DTL_2` and `DTL_3`. I'm just looking for a general idea of how to structure the append query.

Comment: So it would be something like "INSERT into Table B(ID_Number, DTL_1, DTL_2, DTL_3) SELECT ID_Number, DTL_1, DTL_2, DTL_3 from Table A LEFT JOIN Table B ON Table A.ID_Number = Table B.ID_Number WHERE (((Table B.ID_Number) Is Null));" Or something like this. You may need to edit that a bit, but that will get you close.

Comment: im trying to use your query but i dont quite understand the logic. could you possibly write the pseudo code?

Comment: You're basically using an INSERT INTO query, because you're appending data. The rest of the query says "I want these fields, and only give me data where it doesn't exist in Table B". In order to do that, you need to LEFT JOIN Table A to Table B, and only take records that don't exist in Table B ( the "WHERE (((Table B.ID_Number) Is Null));" part).  I'm doing all this under the assumption that ID_Number is the unique identifier that determines if the record already exists in Table B.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible. Depending on how you want to accomplish the updating of table B, there are two possible ways that would be the easiest. The easiest is to make an Update Query that would be run depending on when you want the query to run, i.e. after an update of a field or when closing the form etc. The second way is to create a recordset of the records from Table B in VBA code to update the field. Either way will work equally well and becomes a matter of individual preference.

Comment: If i were to use an update query for Table B (basically copying Table A to B via an update query), than how could I make sure that any records that are updated via a new form for Table B go untouched?