# Split a table in access

Tags: ms-access

I feel like this should be an easy question for someone to answer however despite my numerous searches I have not been able to find an answer  (probably due to lack of dB knowledge).

The problem:  I am building a research dB related to clinical examinations. I have created a main table and a couple of additional tables which have one to many relationships to the main (think, mulitple findings documented in one examination etc.  I have successfully been able to create a Main form with two embedded subforms. This functions as expected.

What I would like to do is break the Main table up into a three individual tables where there are logical differences between groups of fields. This will make the dB easier to revise later on and it will make it easier to find fields.

I would like a record to be created in the two related tables every time i create a record in the first table but I cannot work out how to acheive this.  When I go into the form I would like checkboxes from all three tables displayed and editable on the same page and kept in sync by the RecordID of the main table.

Any help or direction to an example dB would be greatly appreciated.

Regards,

James

Comment: Please have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17526144/1-form-2-tables-ms-access).  If your two tables be related, Access can handle your ask internally.  If they be unrelated then you can write a query to update the second table.

Comment: I reckon you need an additional field / column, not additional tables.